# how to pass value attribute in laravel template blading?

Tags: php, laravel

I am slightly new to Laravel. I have to update a record in the database. For that I am getting a particular `id` upon clicking on edit and from that `id,` I want to populate the `form` with values which are there in the database against that `id.` I have done most of it as I am getting values from the database, but now I have no idea, how to populate it in template blade.

Like in custom PHP, we do that like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value=<?php echo $r['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the view within a route callback or a controller method you pass in the data to the view.

```
$user = User::find(1);

return view('greetings', ['user' => $user]);
```

Within the blade template you now have access to a variable `$user` that contains the model.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users= array();  
$users['data'] = User::find(1);
return View('greetings')->with($users);
```

And then your your view file `greetings.blade.php` use like this.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $data->name }}"/>
```